# Why does Visual Studio 2019 remove my indents when cut-and-pasting F# code?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

In Visual Studio 2019 with Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6, I am seeing unexpected cut-and-paste behavior. If I cut a block of F# code and then paste it somewhere else in my file, the code block is no longer indented to the same level.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a feature, not a bug.

> ...a feature that intelligently indents pasted code based on where your cursor is.
>   *from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-4-6/*

To enable or disable this feature, look at **Tools > Options > Text Editor > F# > Formatting > Reformat indention on paste**.

Comment: Thanks; I had run into that as well and also thought it was a bug (and it doesn't seem very useful to me so far).

Comment: I reported this as a bug, as it certainly feels like one to me. In fact, I'm not convinced that it isn't.

Comment: @JimFoye It would be nice if the feature were a little bit "smarter." Where did you report it as a bug?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/719085/problem-with-indentation-in-f.html

Comment: I like that feature, especially in elmish, if i copy something out of one context into another one.